# Node.js Express, Error handling works only with console.error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am using Node.js Express to create some HTTP REST APIs.
I have methods that call an underline *service* that returns a *Promise* as following:

```
function getAllApps(request, response) {
    appService.getAllApps(request.query.$expand).then(function (apps) {
           response.status(200).send(apps);
        })
}
```

and I map the method as following:

```
var api = express.app;
api.get('/apps', getAllApps);
```

Now, I have introduced error handling as following:

```
function getAllApps(request, response) {
    appService.getApps(request.query.$expand).then(function (apps) {
        response.status(200).send(apps);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
            response.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
```

Which is working as expected except that when an error is encountered, I get the full error stack in the console as following:

```
Express is listening on 127.0.0.1:3000
Web Api ready

Error occurred in Apps Api: Error: Actions is not defined on the model.
```

But my HTTP method return 400 and the body is empty, it contains only the curly brackets:

```
{}
```

Comment: Do you actually throw, or is `apps` empty?

Comment: `.stack` is a non-enumerable property of errors afaik, meaning it will be ignored by `send`. And you don't want it to be sent to the user anyway?

Comment: @Bergi done, apologize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by the error object not having enumerable properties, so `JSON.stringify(new Error("my message"))` will return `{}`. To get the same as the console output, you have to coerect the error object to a string, like so:

```
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
  response.status(500).send("" + err);
});
```

PS: you should use `status(500)` for internal errors.

**EDIT**

If this case does not need a separate error handling mechanism, you could let express to handle your errors:

```
function getAllApps(request, response, next) {
  appService.getApps(request.query.$expand).then(function (apps) {
    response.status(200).send(apps);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    next(err || new Error("Unknown error"));
  });
}
```

And if express' default error handling doesn't give you satisfying results, you can register your own error handler:

```
...

// note that the middleware having 4 parameters makes it an error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
  response.status(500).send("" + err);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the status 400 like so:

```
function getAllApps(request, response) {
  appService.getApps(request.query.$expand).then(function (apps) {
    response.status(200).send(apps);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
        response.json('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
  });
}
```

Comment: But your solution returns 200, which is wrong in REST, this is an Error so I must return 400 or 500